# Redirecting console output to listbox from another thread throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, listbox

I'm trying to redirect console output to a listbox, but when I write text to the console from a different thread it throws an InvalidOperationException

ListBoxWriter:

```
    public class ListBoxWriter : TextWriter
    {
        private ListBox list;
        private StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        public ListBoxWriter(ListBox list)
        {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            content.Append(value);
            if (value == '\n')
            {   
                list.Items.Add(content.ToString());
                content = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is your thread?

Comment: @Kyle my thread doesn't use any of this code but just uses `Console.writeline("text")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the UI from another thread, which means u have to use the dispatcher when adding the item to the list.

```
public class ListBoxWriter : TextWriter
    {
        private ListBox list;
        private StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

        public ListBoxWriter(ListBox list)
        {
            this.list = list;
        }

        public override void Write(char value)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            content.Append(value);
            if (value == '\n')
            {
                list.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() => list.Items.Add(content.ToString())));                    
                content = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }

        public override Encoding Encoding
        {
            get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
        }
    }
```